# ¿Como puedo resolver esto que me sale cuando intento correr una aplicaion?

Tags: android-studio

A penas hoy instalo Android Studio y guiándome por la guía de https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/?hl=es-419 cuando intento correr la aplicación me sale una una caja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando doy clic en Edit Configurations dentro de esa ventana entonces la ventana se entransforma en [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De veraz que no encuentro como resolverlo he buscado y encontrado en varios hilos en inglés el error y las soluciones no me han servido. Por favor si pueden me ayudan, llevo horas buscando la solución

Comment: Hola, haz creado tu proyecto? porque en la imagen parece que no. SI es que si, te podria recomendar que salieras de android studio y entres de nuevo :D

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Parece que el IDE todavía debía descargar algunos ficheros, y la conexión a internet estaba mala, en unas horas mejoró y luego se descargaron los ficheros necesaios y funcionó.

Comment: Perfecto, saludos :D